# Read local images in matlab live editor

Tags: image, matlab

Is it possible to read images from my local machine in MATLAB live editor? I want to try out a function which is available in 2018 version but I only have the 2017 version.
For example, if I want to use the imdiffusefilt(I), in [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdiffusefilt.html) link, when I click "Try this example in browser", I want to be able to read the image from my machine. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes.... use `imread('yourfilename.extension')` . You can add paths, webpages and anything you want to that.

Comment: how can i add the path? can you give an example if the file is in my C drive?

Comment: @Wolfie unfortunately this doesn't work, that's why I need more guesses

Comment: Where is the image? Show us what you tried

Comment: This is what I tried:
I = imread('C:\CCM\HC.bmp');
which is the exact path for the image

Comment: I now realise what you're asking... You're trying to skirt having a license for 2018a by running an in-browser demo with your own image? This won't ever work, or The MathWorks would run out of money for accidentally publishing a complete version of their latest software for free within the documentation! There is a reason why there's also a "Try it in MATLAB" option.

Comment: I see, but I only wanted to try because I dont have the 2018 version.

Comment: Your options are to get R2018a or use an alternative function. If MathWorks let you use the newest functions in-browser without a license then there would never be a point in people purchasing newer versions.